# What Humidifier i need.

Tags: humidity, humidifier

I bought a new home couple of month ago and need to install humidifier. After reading some blogs i am confused that i need humidifier for winter only or for winter and summer ( for AC and heat). Attempted unsuccessful search on Google to find one for both AC and heat. Not sure if it exist. My house is 2500 sqft located in Washington DC(USA) area. I have two units one for ground and main level and second for top floor. Questions in my mind are, what humidifier( Honeywell/Aprilaire etc.) should i buy and of what capacity, Do i need to buy for both units, which one is best (by-pass duct/in duct), Do i even need it for summer.

Appreciate suggestions !!

Comment: Why do you *need* to install a humidifier?  Is the home overly dry during either season?  Is the home drafty, or is it sealed well? What year was the home built?

Comment: It 2015 built. I am planning to install it for this coming winter.

Comment: If the house is sealed well (which it should be if it's a new build), you might not need a humidifier at all. What type of heating unit do you have? Humidifiers are common with gas fired forced air systems, because the combustion of the fuel causes cold dry outside air to be drawn into the home. If the unit draws combustion air directly; or doesn't need air for combustion at all, you may not need a humidifier. Taking showers, and cooking should provide enough humidity.

Answer (score 2):

In Washington, DC you want to remove as much water as possible from the dank soup that passes for summer air. Your AC does that. You definitely do NOT want to add any more humidity in the summer, there.

In a desert climate you might, but then you'd probably also be looking at a swamp cooler, which does both cooling and humidifying - in a DRY climate.

Comment: Thanks for reply !! I am first time home owner. Which i should get for winter. Is ultrasonic good for whole house.

Comment: Live through a winter in the house and see if you even need one...with relatively tight modern construction you may not.

Comment: Obviously written by someone who has been in DC in the summer.  :-)